# Angular pipes aren't working for me in some places... and Stackblitz is awesome

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, pipe

Getting this error:

```
ERROR in src\app\shopping-cart-summary\shopping-cart-summary.component.html(15,42): : Property '$' does not exist on type 'ShoppingCartSummaryComponent'.
```

When I delete the currency pipes it goes away.

I've tried the pipes in every relatively recent combination that I've seen.

```
'$'
"$"
$
"true"
'true'
true
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Order Summary</h5>
        <p class="card-text">You have {{cart.totalItemsCount }} items in your shopping cart.</p>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li *ngFor="let item of cart.items" class="list-group-item">
                {{item.quantity}} x {{item.title}}
                <div class="float-right">
                    {{item.totalPrice | currency: "USD": $ }}
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item font-weight-bold">
                Total
                <div class="float-right">
                    {{cart.totalPrice | currency: "USD": $ }}
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's not a huge deal I can just put a `$` in front of these but I gotta know!

Also I am getting weird behaviour with these pipes in my data table.

I've tried the same combos.

```
<p>
    <a routerLink="/admin/products/new" class="btn btn-primary">New Product</a>
</p>

<p>
    <input #query (keyup)="filter(query.value)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title Search">
</p>

<data-table [items]="items" [itemCount]="itemCount" (reload)="reloadItems($event)">

    <data-table-column [property]="'title'" [header]="'Title'" [sortable]="true" [resizable]="true">
    </data-table-column>
    <data-table-column [property]="'price'" [header]="'Price'" [sortable]="true" [resizable]="true">
    </data-table-column>
    <ng-template #dataTableCell let-item="item"> {{item.price|currency: 'USD' : '$'}}></ng-template>

    <data-table-column [property]="'$key'" [width]="100">
        <ng-template #dataTableCell let-item="item">
            <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', item.$key]">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"
                        aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
        </ng-template>
    </data-table-column>
</data-table>
```

Dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.1.7",
    "angular5-data-table": "^0.5.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.9.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  },
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should actually work, I've actually tested it and you can see it working [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-currency-pipe-examples?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

As you can see

```
{{unitPrice | currency: "USD": $ }}
```

Displays

```
$600.00
```

As a side note... even   `{{unitPrice | currency: "USD": "$" }}` with `"$"` or `true` displays correct value.

Check your package versions... in the stackblitz exapmple I use angular 5, and remember the pipe comes from @angular/common

Comment: It totally is!!

Comment: I'm using a deprecated firebase but everything else is latest within the last month.  Posting my dependencies anyway though

Comment: it is odd... can you check this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11643#issuecomment-247471446  .I know it says date pipe but it is linked to issue with other pipes. bu the way this is only if using AOT which i assumed you are

Comment: Hmmm good eye Im gonna try that. I think I saw this when I first started experiencing the problem bc I wasn't seeing a  'LOCALE_ID' of undefined error.  I'm gonna link this post there too though maybe it'll help.

Comment: maybe do a JIT bundle compilation first and check the pipe actually works there.....

Answer (score 1):

[Currency pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe) works like the following

```
{{item.totalPrice | currency:"USD" }}
```

Also see [pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#parameterizing-a-pipe)

Comment: Thanks... but that's what I did.  Are you trying to tell me there is no whitespace between the colon and the "USD"?

Comment: you didnt, your code clearly says `{{item.totalPrice | currency: "USD": $ }}` which is an extra space, an extra column, an extra space and an extra $

Comment: number_expression | currency[:currencyCode[:display[:digitInfo[:locale]]]]

Comment: you just havent included the display part

Comment: check your currency pipe link

Comment: afaik USD are displayed with $ by default. if you really need to keep the $, it has to be `currency:"USD":"$"`

Comment: you tried already? no whitespace, and $ needs to be quoted. whats the error then? it sould work

Comment: yea, i tried with the quotes... and I'm pretty sure with the whitespace variations too but I'm about to double check. Theres no error or problem besides the $ doesnt show up in either of the cases above.

Comment: Yea, its not working... I thought maybe someone was gonna tell me a special rule about using them in data tables